# Spark Scala SaveMode.Append - does it just append or also update?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

If I have a DF, and I'm writing to a location like this:

`df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(outputFilePath)`

does it only simply append to the `outputFilePath` or does it also update? For example, if I have a row `3 | a | 27`, and append a DF of `3 | a | 200`, it would have two rows? Does this mean I would have to remove table and recreate each time?

Answer (score 4):

> Does it only simply append to the `outputFilePath` or does it also update?

`Append` will only append the contents of the DataFrame to the existing data in that location.

> Does this mean I would have to remove table and recreate each time?

Yes. But you could also take a look at [Delta Lake](https://delta.io/) that brings ACID transactions for Spark using parquet format.

You could use [`MERGE`](https://docs.delta.io/0.4.0/delta-update.html#upsert-into-a-table-using-merge) for that use case:

```
val updatesDF = // updates data 

DeltaTable.forPath(spark, outputFilePath)
  .as("destination")
  .merge(updatesDF.as("updates"), "destination.Id = updates.Id")
  .whenMatched
  .updateExpr(Map("value" -> "updates.value"))
  .whenNotMatched
  .insertExpr(Map("id" -> "updates.id", "value" -> "updates.value"))
  .execute()
```